# How can I deny a commit, in a client-side hook, if the user name/email is incorrect?

Tags: git, githooks

Is there any way I can access the commit author information (author name and email) from Git `commit-msg` hook?

I need to prevent commits which do not have the right email address (like `my.name@company.com`). I can do this on the server side with the `pre-receive` hook or the `update` hook, but is there any way to do the same on the client side?

Of course, I could run

```
git log -1 HEAD
```

in the `post-commit` hook and parse the output, but it's already too late, because the commit has already been created, at that stage. It can only serve as a friendly warning that the push will fail.

Comment: Git actually provides the information to me in environment variables. No need to run git var: GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL, GIT_AUTHOR_DATE and GIT_AUTHOR_NAME

Comment: My thanks for all the comments and insights. I ended up using the environment variables and moved the check from commit-msg to pre-commit hook.

Comment: How about adding this for an answer? I had a similar problem and it was not easy to find a solution on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a `git var` command? For example:

```
$ export EMAIL="arkadiusz@stackoverflow.com"
$ git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT | grep -E -o "<.+>" | sed 's,<,,' | sed 's,>,,'
arkadiusz@stackoverflow.com
$ unset EMAIL
$ git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT | grep -E -o "<.+>" | sed 's,<,,' | sed 's,>,,'
ja@AMDC689
```

Modify ~/.gitconfig:

> ```
> [user]
>         email = a@a.a
> ```

```
$ git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT | grep -E -o "<.+>" | sed 's,<,,' | sed 's,>,,'
a@a.a
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? You make no mention of any client-side hooks...

Comment: OP has asked: `Is there any way I can access the commit author information (author name and email) from Git commit-msg hook?`. Take it easy.